# jQuery mobile collapsed list view with search not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, dom, jquery-mobile

I have created a listview in jquery with a listdivider with a filter. The filter works as expected but as soon as you collapse either of the list dividers, the search subsequently does not work at all,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>jQuery Mobile page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" /> 

  <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
     jQuery.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    });

    </script>
  <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script> 
   <script>
   var hide=0;
   var dpwClone='';
    $(function(){
      $('[data-role="list-divider"]').click(function(element){
          $(this).nextUntil('[data-role="list-divider"]').toggle();
          $("#eServiceList").listview("refresh");
//      $(this).nextUntil('[data-role="list-divider"]').toggle();
    });

    $( "#eServiceList" ).listview( "option", "filterCallback", searchList);

    function searchList( text, searchValue, item ) {
           var result = text.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf( searchValue.toString().toLowerCase() );
           var show = false;
           var hide = true;

        if (result == -1 )
           return hide;

        return show;   
    };
   }); 
  </script>

 </head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Problem nested list views</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <div class="content-primary">   
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="d" data-filter="true" id="eServiceList">
                <li data-role="list-divider" id="dpw" >

                        DPW
                </li>

                <li><a href="#" class="dpw">Inbox</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="dpw">Outbox</a></li>

                   <li data-role="list-divider" id="custo">

                        Customs
                </li>

                <li><a href="#" class="custo">Friends</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="custo">Work</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is the JSfiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddle_one/R8pZH/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `.toggle()` adds to the element an **inline style** attribute `style="display: none;"` or `style="display: block;"`. List items are already enhanced with `display: block;` by jQuery Mobile. Hence, when using `.toggle()` - *when it is visible again* - the element will get `display: block;` twice, inline and in CSS style sheet.

To overcome this problem, use `.toggleClass()` classes rather than inline styling. I fixed your problem by adding a class

```
.hide { display: none !important; }
```

and I used it with `.toggleClass('hide');`

> **[New code](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/HYNrA/)**

Using custom CSS classes to override existing CSS is safer, and keep in mind that for jQuery Mobile, it's better to end each property with `!important` to force override.

Comment: thanks brother your fixed worked like a charm :), i have struggling with this for almost a week now

Comment: If I could upvote this 1,000 times, I would. The concept of using a class instead .show /.hide when showing/ hiding items in the listview no longer was breaking my search. Thanks.